# How to choose combination of Firefox and Selenium Webdriver versions for web automation?

Tags: firefox, automation, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

If we choose latest version of Firefox or latest version of Selenium-Webdriver, we couldn't automate few tests because of either something not supported in latest version of Firefox or latest version of Selenium-WebDriver.

In such situation, which combinations of Firefox version and Selenium Webdriver version should we choose? (I mean, should we go for one/two version back of latest Firefox version and/or one/two version back of latest selenium webdriver version or some other combination?)

Comment: Well are your users likely to be using the up to date versions of Firefox?

Comment: Yes Arran, our users are likely to be using up to date versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use whatever your acceptance criteria states. If you have to support an earlier version of Firefox because it is in a contract or requirement, then you must test that version and use whatever version of selenium is necessary

Comment: Thanks, RobbieWareham!

Answer (score 1):

The Latest piece of softwares are always preferable, But the selection of browser version is highly depend upon your application under test.

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of selenium (v3), check out the selenium-docker releases here, https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/releases, you can even use docker to test all the Selenium/Firefox combinations easily.  For older versions of selenium (v2), check out the selenium site here, https://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp .
I recommend moving to the docker path for local testing; then you can also use the docker files to migrate to cloud platforms.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you download latest webdriver version, make sure that you look into https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG

to check the latest browser version support.

Comment: link is broken.